# jQuery UI autocomplete: no mouse selection

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I am developing a search-form for my website and I plan to use JQuery UI autocomplete widget to suggest values as the user types. So far, the suggestions do work.

The problem is that when users select a value from the list, the input field is not updated. The same problem seems to have been reported before, for example: [Jquery UI Autocomplete doesn't allow options to be selected with mouse anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379439/jquery-ui-autocomplete-doesnt-allow-options-to-be-selected-with-mouse-anymore) but no solution was published.

The code is as simple as possible:

```
<script> 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];

    jQuery("#tbauthor").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
    });   

});
</script>
<div id="primary" class="aside main-aside sidebar">
    <form style="font-size: 10px;" name="search-news" action="." method="get">
    <table border= "0">

        <tr class="advanced"><td>Cerca per autor</td><td><input type="text" id="tbauthor" name="autor" /></td></tr>

    </table>
</form>
</div>
```

I am using wordpress 3.5 with Arras theme, JQuery 1.8.3 and jQuery UI 1.9.2 (already included in wordpress installation). To load the autocomplete library I call to wp_enqueue_script in header.php Here is an excerpt (header.php). My only guess is that I have a problem with the libraries loaded:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-tabs', null, array('jquery-ui-core', 'jquery'), null, false); 
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-autocomplete', null, array('jquery-ui-core', 'jquery'), null, false);
```

**UPDATE, as the question was solved, the example is no longer a non-working example**: Finally, <strike>you can see the non-working example in my site: http://www.cabanyal.com/nou/resultat/?id=1994</strike>

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: fore firefox 17 the input value is getting updated..

Comment: I think you have versioning problem. Here is your example in action: http://jsfiddle.net/v9bSa/

Comment: @Razmig I did not know about jsfiddle. Thanks, but I still don't understand what is wrong with my example.

Comment: @redDevil Firefox 18 and Opera 12.12 don't react to mouse selection...

Comment: Your jQuery validation plugin is causing a conflict with the autocomplete. I was able to replicate the problem here by including the jQuery validator plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/VAna6/1/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WordPress theme is including an obsolete version of the jQuery validator plugin which is causing a conflict with the autocomplete:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.cabanyal.com/nou/wp-content/themes/arras/js/jquery.validate.min.js'></script>
```

I was able to replicate the issue here:  [jsfiddle.net/VAna6/1](http://jsfiddle.net/VAna6/1)

Change the script to the most [recent version](https://raw.github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/master/jquery.validate.js) and the autocomplete should work as presented here: http://jsfiddle.net/VAna6/2/.

Comment: Solved! As you pointed out, the Arras theme was using n old version of jquery.validate.min.js (v1.5.1). I updated the script and now it works like a charm.

Comment: Great! I would also contact the theme author and let them know to update their validator script if you get a chance :) - will help minimize number of victims down the road!